# Fill blanks in column from cells above

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have data in a single column in the following format :

```
Column Header

Adam 
----
----
----
John
----
----
Smith
----
----
----
```

I want to copy the names into the blank cells below each.

Is there a command for this?

Answer (score 2):

There is not really, unless you have a macro.

Otherwise, you can use an additional column and an `IF()`.

1. To do this, insert a new column to the right of the column you have. Let's say that the column you have is column A and the new column is B.
2. Put the formula in cell B2:

   ```
   =IF(A2="",B1,A2)
   ```
3. Drag the column down till the last cell in your table.
4. Copy the whole column (excluding the header) and paste as values onto column A. You can then remove/delete column B.

Comment: the "paste as values" is important!

Answer (score 1):

There's a quick&dirty solution that will do the job very efficiently - though it's only viable if you only need to modify the data once. If you get repeated updates, it's better to go with Jerry' answer.

Here's the quick way:

1. Select column A (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>)
2. Goto (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>) -> Special (<kbd>A</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>) -> Blank cells (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd>) -> Ok (<kbd>Enter</kbd>) - this will select you all the blank fields in column A
3. Enter the formula `=<ReferenceForCellAbove>` - but instead of using <kbd>Enter</kbd>, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>! `<ReferenceForCellAbove>` you get by simply pressing <kbd>ArrowUp</kbd> after entering the `=`. This will fill all the selected blank cells with the data from the cell above
4. optional: Paste the values:

   1. Select column A (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>)
   2. Copy (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>)
   3. Paste special (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd>) - Values (<kbd>V</kbd>)

Done!